# How to Clear JTable Cell on double mouse click

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I would like to have a Table Cell cleared when the user double clicks on it. The cells I set as NON editable I can double click on and use setValueAt to clear the cell. For the cells I have that ARE editable, I double click on, I use setValueAt to clear it, the TableModel shows the cleared cell but the GUI does not.  When I move to the next cell, the original value stays put.
I tried settinbgviewportview again but that did not work.  It seems when it is an editable cell, and you double click, the jTable expects keyboard input.
Below is the code which should display the issue.  The first column is not editable. The other three are.  When you double click on the first column, the cell is cleared.  When you double click on the other columns, the cell receives focus but the cell is not cleared in the GUI.

What am I missing?

```
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;


public class test extends javax.swing.JFrame {

   
    /**
     * Creates new form test
     */
    public test() {
        initComponents();
        jTable1.addMouseListener(new TableMouseListener());
      
    }
  

                            
    private void initComponents() {

        jScrollPane2 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
        jTable1 = new javax.swing.JTable();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        jTable1.setModel(new javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel(
            new Object [][] {
                {"xxxxxx", "yyyyyy", "zzzzzz", "222222"}
            },
            new String [] {
                "Title 1", "Title 2", "Title 3", "Title 4"
            }
        ) {
            boolean[] canEdit = new boolean [] {
                false, true, true, true
            };

            public boolean isCellEditable(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
                return canEdit [columnIndex];
            }
        });
        jScrollPane2.setViewportView(jTable1);

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap(253, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addComponent(jScrollPane2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 375, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addContainerGap())
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addComponent(jScrollPane2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 275, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addContainerGap(14, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );

        pack();
    }                     

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new test().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
public class TableMouseListener implements java.awt.event.MouseListener {

        @Override
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
         
        }

        @Override
        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
        
        }

        @Override
        public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
            if (e.getClickCount()==2){
                javax.swing.JTable t=(javax.swing.JTable)e.getSource();
                int irow=t.getSelectedRow();
                int icol=t.getSelectedColumn();
                t.getModel().setValueAt("", irow, icol);
            }
          
        }

        @Override
        public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
//         
        }

        @Override
        public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
          
        }
    }
    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane2;
    private javax.swing.JTable jTable1;
    // End of variables declaration                   
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What am I missing?

When you double click on an editable cell the data from the model is moved to the editor (before it has been cleared).

When you finish editing the cell the data from the editor is saved to the model.

So you need to clear the data in the editor (not the model) as the editor is displayed:

```
jTable1 = new javax.swing.JTable()
{
    @Override
    public boolean editCellAt(int row, int column, EventObject e)
    {
        boolean result = super.editCellAt(row, column, e);
        final Component editor = getEditorComponent();

        if (editor != null && editor instanceof JTextComponent)
        {
            ((JTextComponent)editor).setText("");
        }

        return result;
    }
};
```

Comment: Yes, I figured it out.  Thank You for answering to quickly!

Answer (score 0):

After clicking editable cell you start editing its contents. To cancel editing, after you `setValueAt` you can use:

```
    jTable1.editingCanceled(new ChangeEvent(this));
```

to stop editing and restore the value from the model (your new empty value).

Comment: Thank You.  I actually figured it out more or less.  I get the editing component and set the text in THAT.  But that you for offering a solution so quickly.